# Wouldnt it would be wise to just become a sanyasi?

Tags: moksha, sanyasi

Wouldnt it would be wise to just become a sanyasi? I knw everybody has to do karma but a sanyasi lifes is relatively simple.Why to marry and bring another generation in this complicated world?If all became sanyasis then the wrold will clear out and all will get moksha.

Comment: Who said all will get moksha?
Only a handful of ppl have the grit to pursue the path of Jnana Yoga till the end.Most of us are not even concerned with moksha,we are just attracted by the fruits i.e the siddhis obtained  by sadhana and upasana.
If you think a sanyasis life is as simple as you think;pls read abt life of Swami Vivekananda.You would actually start crying.That man has given up so much and suffered so much that you could never even dream of !

Comment: Fact is we common people full of ego think its really easy to be sanyasi after all we just have to pray to God, beg for food and live freely right with no attachment?Hell we dont even know what taking Sanyas is! Trustmeits so hard to give up material things when right from birth you are conditioned by Prakriti to think only worldly things would provide tou all the pleasure you want.Whenever one tries to go against the natural flow of Prakriti, a tremendously strong resistance is produced and Prakriti(i.e Avidya Maya) which tries to drag you down into the world again.

Comment: Only once in many years is a ripe soul like Swami Vivekananda born on earth who is free from the 6 enemies of the mind. Only people like him who are ready to sacrifice all attachments at a moments notice and have a tremendously strong urge to find the Absolute Truth , so strong that you ignore all  bodily requirements just for even getting a little bit closer to the Truth are those who are fit to take sanyaas at a young age.

Comment: Fact is all **cannot** become sannyasi.It is not for common people.
We cant even control our petty lust let alone other senses.Study about the lives of saints like Swami Vivekananda,Ramakrishna Paramahamsa,Sripad HH Adi Shakaracharya,Sripad HH Ramanujacharya,Ramana Mahrishi,Sant Jnaneshwar,Sant Ramdas Samartha,Sant Namdev,Tukaram and many more legendary saints and observe just how strong was their desire to attain God/experience  the truth.Then compare yours.

Comment: Why to marry and bring another generation in this complicated world?
You are right marrying is totally optional for those on the spiritual path.If you think you can handle your lust just fine(most of us think that but we cannot) can remain as a brahmchari till death.Otherwise join the grihastha ashram.Better option is you marry but adopt a child instead and illuminate his life by taking charge of it.

Comment: We also have a member here who is also a sanyaasi here @Swami Vishwananda 
He could probably enlighten us with his superior knowledge regarding dangers faced after taking sanyaasa.

Answer (score 6):

It won't be wise. Because you are having certain goals/desires for which you want to become a Sannyasi. For example "life will be simpler in comparison .." is one such goal/motive.

One should become a Sannyasi only when a genuine desire for renunciation/liberation has emerged in one's mind. Only when one has grown in him a genuine feeling of detachment. If a person becomes a Sannyasi without proper feeling of detachment then he becomes degraded by that act.

See the following verses from the Narada Parivrajaka Upanishad:

> **"Only when indifference toward all things has arisen in their minds, do they seek renunciation. Otherwise a man shall become an outcaste.**
>
> "Let a wise man renounce when he is detached but live at home so long
> as he is attached. For the vile Brahmin who renounces while he is
> attached will go to hell.
>
> "If his tongue, sexual organ, stomach, and hands are all under
> complete control, [139] a Brahmin may renounce while he is still a
> student and unmarried.

([Narada Parivrajaka Upanishad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naradaparivrajaka_Upanishad) is attached to the Atharva Veda and it is included among the so-called Sannyasa Upanishads category.)

Comment: Nice answer Rickross Ji!

Comment: Thank you ..... @Rāmachandra

Answer (score 0):

‘Dharma', ‘Artha', ‘Kama', and ‘Moksha' are the four goals of life. They do not come in play separately. For a good(perfect) life an individual has to experience and exercise all of them to fulfill the aim of this life and liberate the soul. Only some exceptional soul can adopt a life of sanyasi and escape the other other fields. Just to jump into sanyas may be escapism. I have known some friends doing it and getting nowhere.

As for the second question, to continue our exitance, nature has made the arrangement of reproduction. We human beings have started behaving like God and have interfered with many of these natural processes. Here I must say only the time will tell if our interventions are judicial. According to some estimate, for the population to reproduce itself at current numbers, the “total fertility rate” needs to be 2,100 births per 1,000 women of childbearing age over their lifetime. If you look around, will notice that this rate is dropping all over the world, with probably exception in some religious group. Then again if don’t reproduce, at one stage the world may “collapse”, of course one has a choice in this regard.

Comment: What about second part of my question shouldnt we do something about the population?@Jay Thakar

Answer (score -1):

Vedic System prescribes four aashrams namely Brahmachari, Grihasta, Vaanaprastha and Sannyasa. By default, one has to follow the sequence mentioned. Firstly, we need to understand the fact that - had it been good to have only Sannayasa Aashram, Vedas wouldn't mention the four aashrams. Secondly, one should have a Guru who would initiate an individual into Sannayas Aashram based on one's eligibility. So, it's always a combination of the Guru's and Shishya's wisdom that enables one to get initiated into the Sannyasa Aashram.

Answer (score -2):

As for the second question, to continue our exitance, nature has made the arrangement of reproduction. We human beings have started behaving like God and have interfered with many of these natural processes. Here I must say only the time will tell if our interventions are judicial. According to some estimate, for the population to reproduce itself at current numbers, the “total fertility rate” needs to be 2,100 births per 1,000 women of childbearing age over their lifetime. If you look around, will notice that this rate is dropping all over the world, with probably exception in some religious group. Then again if don’t reproduce, at one stage the world may “collapse”, of course one has a choice in this regard.